# How to make Pinterest button grab an image URL from a mysqli fetch array

Tags: php, image

I just added a Pinterest button to my site and I'm not quite sure how to make the Pinterest button grab the img URL from my mysqli_fetch_array code. As of now when I click the button and try to pick a board to pin it to, I get this error:

Oops! You need to upload an image or provide the 'image_url' parameter

On top of that I have this in a thumbnail slider gallery with four different pictures. If it helps to see this, my site is buyfarbest.com . Do I need to do anything different with the Pinterest HTML code that was provided from the site to grab the img?

```
<div class="pinItButton"><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-height="28" target="_blank"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_28.png" /></a>
```

My code from my page:

```
<div class="viewproductpiccontainer">
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="pinItButton"><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-height="28" target="_blank"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_28.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <ul class='big'>
        <li>
            <?php $result=m ysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products where product_id =".$_GET[ 'view_product']); if($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $products[$row[ 'product_id']]=$ row; echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row[ 'img'] . "' alt='Product Pic'>"; } ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='controls'>
        <li class='prev'>&lt;</li>
        <li class='next'>&gt;</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='thumb' id="bxslider-horizontal">
        <div class="bxslider">
            <div class="slide">
                <li>
                    <?php $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products where product_id =".$_GET[ 'view_product']); if($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $products[$row[ 'product_id']]=$ row; echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/".$row[ 'img'] . "' alt='Product Pic'>"; } ?>
                </li>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Is there anyway I can make this work with the way I have all of this setup? If it helps to see it, my website is buyfarbest.com . If you go to products and then click on any of them it will take you to the details of that product. Hover your mouse over the large image. The Pinterest button will then appear.

HTML source code added:

```
<div class="viewproductpiccontainer">
                        <div class="slideshow">
                        <div class="pinItButton"><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-height="28" target="_blank"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_28.png" /></a></div>
                            <ul class='big'>

                                <li>
                                    <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/blueCollar.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                       
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/blueCollar2.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                  </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/allCollars.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                   </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/allCollars2.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                  </li>
                                <!--<li>
                                    <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img22/4640/6a5q.jpg" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img513/4973/h6g3.jpg" />
                                </li>-->
                            </ul>
                            <ul class='controls'>
                                <li class='prev'>&lt;</li>
                                <li class='next'>&gt;</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class='thumb' id="bxslider-horizontal">
                                <div class="bxslider">
                                    <div class="slide"><li>
                                    <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/blueCollar.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                       </li></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><li>
                                        <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/blueCollar2.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                      </li></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><li>
                                        <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/allCollars.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                       </li></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><li>
                                        <img class='sizedimg' src='productpics/allCollars2.jpg' alt='Product Pic'>                                      </li></div>
                                    <!--<div class="slide"><li>
                                        <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img22/4640/6a5q.jpg" />
                                    </li></div>
                                    <div class="slide"><li>
                                        <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img513/4973/h6g3.jpg" />
                                    </li></div>-->
                                </div>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Can include generated `html` at Question ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I added the HTML source code. I want which ever picture they are on in the main image (the .big class) if they select the Pinterest button, for that image to move forward to Pinterest.

Comment: Can describe _"which ever picture they are on"_ ? Is expected result when hover on `.big` image , `src` of image set at `button` handler ?

Comment: @guest271314 well the page this code is in will be for the current product selected. So any picture will really work. Ideally, whichever pictured they have selected in the slider is the one that I would like to be carried forward.

Comment: What is _"carried forward"_ ? How are images "selected" at slider ?

Comment: @guest271314 Right now I don't believe anything is being carried forward. That is the main reason I asked the question. The images are selected by clicking in the certain image.